# How to represent instantiation of DocumentClient in Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-cosmosdb

Having a hard time figuring out how to do the same thing in powershell as the followings lines:

(in namespace Microsoft.Azure.Documents)

DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri("endpoint"), "authKey")

Database database = client.CreateDatabaseQuery().Where(d => d.Id == "collectionName").AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()

Can anyone help? 
tx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look here: https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2014/08/23/using-powershell-to-seed-azure-documentdb-from-blob-storage/

It shows you how use the authKey endpoint uri in a raw REST request.

Also, study the REST API for DocumentDB here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn781481.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.

It'll allow you to look up how to do more operations following the Alexandre's example.

There is also this powershell commandlet DLL that makes many of the operations easy: https://github.com/savjani/Azure-DocumentDB-Powershell-Cmdlets

Comment: yes, i had reviewed alexandre's example, but he goes off and does it in a cmdlet.. which is fine, but i'm missing how to Get a 'database' object,  (not create one)... and was hoping i didn't have to try and edit his cmdlet just to do it.  (note i did mention i wanted to do it in powershell).

Comment: Your question didn't originally ask about creating a query, just how to use the url and auth, so that's why I didn't address that. Regardless, you should be able to use the REST API docs to figure out how to send in a query. You'll want to use a POST and populate the body with a JSON object that contains a string that has the query (as specified in the REST API docs).

Comment: Tx Larry... i got what i needed from using the savjani project. that solution is all c# in a cmdlet but in the end i can use it.   so even though it doesn't answer my question directly.  i'll mark it as the answer.